# fetching specific data from database using where clause providing values from user to print the data related to him using python

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

i'm trying to print the files related to a user using user name and password

i'm entering value in a box as password from user, than trying to fetch its data from database using where clause

```
    #func i'm using to fetch data
    def fun():
    p=int(password.get())
    d=sign.execute("select * from login_details where Name=?",p)
    for x in d:
       print(x)


    #entry box to get the password
    password=tk.Entry()
    password.pack()
```

this is the error i'm getting

```
    sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The 
    current statement uses 1, and there are 0 supplied.
```

Comment: let me know if my answer below helped, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out:

```
        def fun():
            p=int(password.get())
            sign.execute('select * from login_details where Name= ?',(p,))
            all_rows = sign.fetchall()
            print(all_rows)


        #entry box to get the password
        password=tk.Entry()
        password.pack()
```

You were missing the column when you passed in the `p` parameter. Also i wnet along and gave another way of printing all the rows in the table.

Also I noticed that you are trying to a where clause on Name, (which I assume is a string) but you are passing in an integer? Is that a mistake?